CMake pkg-config on Windows 11 returns error: "required by 'virtual:world', not found"
I'm preparing to compile a GTK+-3.0 test application on Windows 11. I have a CMake configuration that runs well on linux.
I've installed GTK 3.0 with msys2, following this instruction: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/
I've updated the global environment variable PATH (appending C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin) and I've created the global environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH, containing the path to the directory with all the .pc files (C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig). When I run pkg-config.exe --list-all, the list contains GTK+-3.0 and running pkg-config.exe --print-variables --debug gtk+-3.0 gives a reasonable output without any errors.
I am using this in my CMake configuration:
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET "gtk+-3.0")

On Windows, I am getting the error:
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:35 (pkg_check_modules)

While I was experimenting with the configuration of the environment variables, I was getting the same error, every time the PKG_CONFIG_PATH was not pointing to the directory containing the file gtk+-3.0.pc. It seems to me, that required by 'virtual:world', not found is more of a generic error for a missing .pc file than actually a missing requirement.
I have already been looking at this article: set PKG_CONFIG_PATH in cmake but the proposed solution didn't help me. When I set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH in the CMake configuration too, I'm still getting the same error.
I do not use Windows very often at all. It is not unlikely, that I've been missing something that's very obvious to an experienced Windows user.

Now it (almost) works after I manually created the global environment variable MSYSTEM. Build configuration was created, but I'm still getting some CMake errors for non-existant pathes and it doesn't build yet.

I am still getting the error CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: Imported target "PkgConfig::GTK" includes non-existent path "/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0" in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES. repeatedly.

Don't set environment variables manually (PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, ...). Open MSYS2 MINGW64 terminal in the Start menu and they'll be set for you. Install CMake in MSYS2 (pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake) and use it instead of the official one, at the very least it defaults to using MSYS2 compilers instead of MSVC.

So you're saying that setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH affects pkg-config but not cmake?

"So you're saying that setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH affects pkg-config but not cmake?" Yes, on windows command. So far I don't have cmake configured inside MSYS. Edit: I don't know if PKG_CONFIG_PATH is the problem here. As I mentioned, it started building (an incomplete) configuration after I set the environment variable MSYSTEM.

"Install CMake in MSYS2 ..." OK, I've done that. I also installed gcc and set it as CMAKE_C_COMPILER. cmake starts with saying -- The C compiler identification is GNU 14.1.0 and then it keeps failing with the message: The C compiler "/mingw64/bin/cc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Don't set CMAKE_C_COMPILER manually, having to do it is again of something being misconfigured. cmake will pick the correct compiler automatically. I assume you have installed mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc?

Don't set CMAKE_C_COMPILER manually, having to do it is again a sign of something being misconfigured. cmake will pick the correct compiler automatically. I assume you have installed mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc?

"I assume you have installed mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc?" Yes, I did. I expected CMake to automatically pick that one, but it didn't. That's why I set CMAKE_C_COMPILER.

What compiler does it pick automatically? And what does which cmake say?

I've used this https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/download/2024-07-27/msys2-x86_64-20240727.exe to install MSYS2. I was also installing some UCRT64, but when that didn't work I switched to MINGW64. Could that be a problem? Could reinstalling MSYS2 help?

"What compiler does it pick automatically?" /mingw64/bin/cc.exe - "And what does which cmake say?" /mingw64/bin/cmake

Hmm, it is the correct compiler, cc is another name for gcc, cc --version will confirm this. (Sorry, didn't notice you've already mentioned the compiler before...)

UCRT64 vs MINGW64 shouldn't matter, both work equally well. Yep, try reinstalling, and this time document every package that you install.

With standard CMake (Windows installation instead of inside MSYS), I was just able to build the project with gcc compiler (instead of MSVC). I will still try to reinstall MSYS and get it to work. (lots of edits in this post)

"cc is another name for gcc, cc --version will confirm this." You're right. I didn't know that they were the same.

I've reinstalled MSYS64. Not sure if I used "run as Administrator" when I installed MSYS64 the first time, this time I did. Instead of C:\tools\msys64 I used the default path C:\msys64 this time.

pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain base-devel
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
pacman -S openssh
pacman -S git

configured ~/.ssh/config for git

git checkout repository

changed into build dir

cmake ../Repository -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
ninja -j24

worked!

Good! FYI, msys2 git is known to be laggy, the official one should be faster. And running as admin shouldn't be necessary.

Either calling CMake from the MSYS2 environment or additionally setting the global environment variable MSYSTEM when calling the windows installation of CMake from Windows command prompt, both worked for me to solve this issue.
Calling CMake from the MSYS2 environment seems to be the easier and more recommendable option here.

This answer is mostly based on the very helpful comments that HolyBlackCat provided and also on my own results. Please don't hesitate, if you can provide a more profound answer to the question or add a comment, if you can help me to improve this answer.
